# Need Terminal command to ping every second, pause and then repeat

Tags: terminal, network, bash, zsh, ping

I want to find a Terminal command that will provide a timestamped ping every second for a period of time (say 5 minutes) and then pause for another period of time (say 30 minutes) and then repeat that process until I stop it. I will need to let it run for days.

In other words, what I want is sort of a combination of the following 2:

```
1) ping 8.8.8.8 | while read line; do echo `date` - $line; done
2) ping 8.8.8.8 | while read line; do echo `date` - $line; sleep 1800; done
```

(1) provides a ping listing every second with a timestamp, while (2) does the same thing but every 30 minutes instead of every second. I can use (1) but it generates way more data than I need. (2) provides the pauses I need but cannot catch the events I'm looking for (which last about 4 seconds, see below).

Although not needed to answer my question, the reason I want this is to deal with an intermittent internet connectivity problem. By using (1) above I have found that most of the time my internet connection is fine, but every couple of days or so there will be periods (lasting hours) during which I get unusually high pings for about 4 seconds, and this repeats every 15 seconds or so. But using (1) to figure that out meant a lot of unnecessary data collection. Also, I have a separate script which will plot the data and there are just way too many data points to plot conveniently since I need to collect for days.

I'm running OS 13.2 on a MacAir M1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while :; do
    ping --apple-time -c $((5*60)) 8.8.8.8
    sleep $((30*60))
    echo # if required to separate the blocks
done
```

`--apple-time` obviously is an Apple addition which is quite useful for what you need here, the output would look like

```
15:50:24.467213 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=114 time=2.991 ms
15:50:25.471150 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=1.805 ms
15:50:26.476259 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=1.822 ms
15:50:27.480521 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=114 time=1.832 ms
15:50:28.485576 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=114 time=1.785 ms
```

If you just want the timestamp and the ping time, you can use `sed` to filter out the noise:

```
$ ping --apple-time -c $((5*60)) 8.8.8.8 | sed -n -E 's/(.*) 64 bytes.*time=(.*) ms/\1 \2/p'
19:11:49.447810 2.928
19:11:50.450692 1.836
19:11:51.455125 1.829
```

---

To accomplish the same without relying on Apple-specific options, you can also just take your second command and put the `sleep` outside of the `while read line` loop:

```
while :; do
    ping -c $((5*60)) 8.8.8.8 | while read line; do echo $(date): "$line"; done
    sleep $((30*60))
    echo # if required to separate the blocks
done
```

or, again without the noise

```
while :; do
    ping -c $((5*60)) 8.8.8.8 | while read line; do 
        echo $(date): $(sed -n -E 's/.*time=(.*) ms/\1/p' <<<$line)
    done
    sleep $((30*60))
    echo # if required to separate the blocks
done
```

Comment: This is great -- it does the most important part of what I want. The only thing I don't like is all the "non-raw data" it outputs between each set of raw data. In other words, I'd rather have ONLY the timestamp and ping time lines (as you showed in your output example) and nothing else.  The reason is that I take that raw data and process it to make a chart, and getting rid of the non-raw data means more work.  Do you have a way around that? In any event, this qualifies as an answer even as it is. Thanks again.

Comment: @TonyM see the edits

Comment: I tried many things but can't get your "without the noise" code to work. But that's okay. The other code is great. Thanks again.

Comment: @tonym which one did you try, the First or the second? And what was the error you got?

Comment: @tonym ah, the second one didn't work, should be fixed now.

Comment: Agreed -- it now runs. However, I'm confused -- I don't see any pause in that code. Is there a 30*60 pause there that I just don't see? To me the pause/sleep is very important

Comment: @TonyM That was left as an exercise for the reader :-) Should work with the pause now (even though the 3 MB a day it generates without the pause/sleep will not overflow your drive).

Comment: The last set of code now works for me. It's really clean, although it still adds a lines without ping data (1 before each set, 4 after). But this is just checking the teeth of a gift horse. As I said, the original post did the job. Thanks again